# Select those customers that only has product A or B

Tags: excel

I have a list with column `Customer` and `Product` and want to create a new column `Select` where I want to select with `1` for those customers that have `A` or `B`, else `0`. The expected output:

For example, I do not want to select Customer 3 because he has `A`, `B` and `C`. I only want those customers with `A` or `B`, or `A` and `B`.

I have tried this `=SUM(1/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10;A2;$B$2:$B$10;"A")+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10;A2;$B$2:$B$10;"B")))`, but it didn't work, and only gave weird numbers or errors.

[image]

Comment: count if the total number of that customer id is equal to the number of that id with product A + the number of that id with product B. Thiswill be true for customer 1 because `2` = `1` + `1`,  false for customer 3 because `3` is not equal to `1` + `1`, and true for customer 5 because `1` = `1` + `0` etc. The equation will have a form like `=COUNTIF(..., A2)=(COUNTIF(..., "A") + COUNTIF(..., "B"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Try this formula:

```
=--NOT(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$10=A2),--($B$2:$B$10<>"A"),--($B$2:$B$10<>"B")))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking

```
=--AND(OR(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$10,A2,B$2:B$10,"A"),COUNTIFS(A$2:A$10,A2,B$2:B$10,"B")),NOT(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$10,A2,B$2:B$10,"<>A",B$2:B$10,"<>B")))
```

but this seems a bit long!

@JvDV and @Justyna MK are absolutely right logically, you could miss out the test for A or B because if it isn't A or B, it must be something else and this would disqualify it, so you can just test for Not A and Not B. In my version it would be

```
=--NOT(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$10,A2,B$2:B$10,"<>A",B$2:B$10,"<>B"))
```

The only difference would be if you had a blank for the product, where my original formula would not count it but the reduced formula would:

[image]

Comment: You can sum the countifs Tom. Like so: `SUM(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$10,A2,B$2:B$10,{"A","B"}))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option, counting the times customer ordered product A OR B wrapped in a `SUM(COUNTIFS(ColA,Customer,ColB,Product A OR B))` fashion, against the amount of rows of that particular customer in the database.

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=N(SUM(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,{"A","B"}))=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10,A2))
```

An even more basic formula would be:

```
=N(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,"<>A",$B$2:$B$10,"<>B")=0)
```

Where we just test if there are any product bought by the customer that are neither product A nor product B.

Drag down.